How to show a grounding shadow as in AR Quick Look?
While showing a .USDZ model using a QLPreviewController I get a grounding shadow out of the box. However, when I load the same model in the ARView there is no such shadow. Why is it hidden and is it possible to show it ?  Or do I have to create a custom shadow ?


(VR-like) AR mode with Grounding Shadow component
The answer is quite obvious: since ARQuickLook doesn't allow you customize anything in your scene (it's a ready-to-use solution), then if you want to implement everything that is activated in ARQuickLook by default (be it collision shapes, gestures, grounding shadows, playing animations, etc) in ARView or in RealityView you'll have to implement this from scratch.
RealityKit 4.0 (iOS 18.0+) allows you generate grounding shadows from the perspective of another entity that receives the first entity's shadow. In the previous version of RealityKit you would have to use a directional or spot lights for this.
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        ARViewContainer().ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}


struct ARViewContainer : UIViewRepresentable {
    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    let anchor = AnchorEntity()
    
    init() {
        arView.environment.lighting.intensityExponent = 1.001
        arView.environment.background = .color(.white)
    }
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        // Biplane's Entity
        let entity = try! Entity.load(named: "biplane")
        entity.position.y = 0.05
        anchor.addChild(entity)

        // Biplane's ModelEntity
        let model = entity.findEntity(named: "toy_biplane_bind") as! ModelEntity
        model.components[GroundingShadowComponent.self] = 
                                                 .init(castsShadow: true, 
                                                       receivesShadow: false)
        // Shadow plane
        let mesh = MeshResource.generatePlane(width: 0.5,
                                              depth: 0.5,
                                       cornerRadius: 0.25)
        let material = SimpleMaterial()
        let shadowPlane = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh, materials: [material])
        shadowPlane.components[GroundingShadowComponent.self] = 
                                                       .init(castsShadow: false, 
                                                             receivesShadow: true)
        anchor.addChild(shadowPlane)            
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: ARView, context: Context) { }
}

Here's some kind of tracked "VR mode" (camera feed is obscured by ARView's white BG).


AR mode with Occlusion material
For AR mode, you could use DirectionalLight object with a non-opaque material catching a shadow, but for some reason OcclusionMaterial causes the surface to be "overexposed". I hope that this bug will be fixed in future versions. It's quite possible that there's some parameter that can remove the "overexposed surface" effect of the plane, but I have not found it.
struct ARViewContainer : UIViewRepresentable {
    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    let anchor = AnchorEntity()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        // Biplane's Entity
        let entity = try! Entity.load(named: "biplane")
        entity.position.y = 0.05
        anchor.addChild(entity)
        
        // Light
        let sun = DirectionalLight()
        sun.shadow = .init()
        sun.light.intensity = 4000
        sun.light.color = .white
        sun.orientation = .init(angle: -.pi/2, axis: [1,0,0])
        anchor.addChild(sun)
        
        // Shadow plane
        let mesh = MeshResource.generatePlane(width: 0.5,
                                              depth: 0.5,
                                       cornerRadius: 0.25)

        let material = OcclusionMaterial(receivesDynamicLighting: true) // !!!
        
        let shadowPlane = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh, materials: [material])
        anchor.addChild(shadowPlane)
        
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: ARView, context: Context) { }
}


VR mode (.nonAR)
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        ARViewContainer().ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct ARViewContainer : UIViewRepresentable {
    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    let anchor = AnchorEntity()
    
    init() {
        arView.cameraMode = .nonAR
        arView.environment.background = .color(UIColor(white: 0.975, alpha: 1))
    }
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        // Biplane's Entity
        let entity = try! Entity.load(named: "biplane")
        entity.position.y = 0.05
        anchor.addChild(entity)
        print(entity)
        
        // Perspective Camera
        let camera = PerspectiveCamera()
        camera.position = [-0.13, 0.2, 0.7]
        camera.orientation = .init(angle: -.pi/16, axis: [1,1,0])
        anchor.addChild(camera)

        // Biplane's ModelEntity
        let model = entity.findEntity(named: "toy_biplane_bind") as! ModelEntity
        model.components[GroundingShadowComponent.self] =
                                                 .init(castsShadow: true,
                                                       receivesShadow: false)
        // Shadow plane
        let mesh = MeshResource.generatePlane(width: 0.5,
                                              depth: 0.5,
                                       cornerRadius: 0.25)
        let material = SimpleMaterial()
        let shadowPlane = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh, materials: [material])
        shadowPlane.components[OpacityComponent.self] = .init(opacity: 0.9)
        shadowPlane.components[GroundingShadowComponent.self] =
                                                       .init(castsShadow: false,
                                                             receivesShadow: true)
        anchor.addChild(shadowPlane)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        return arView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ view: ARView, context: Context) { }
}



what is "toy_biplane_bind" and how is it different from "biplane" ?

print(entity) and you'll see a full scene hierarchy in console. "toy_biplane_bind" is a name of a ModelEntity (which based on a ModelComponent). You will only be able to apply GroundingShadowComponent to the ModelEntity. This won't work with a regular Entity.

I used the load(named:) method (not the loadModel(named:) one, which loads a flattened entity) to preserve the original hierarchy.

And you can turn off all the warnings in the Xcode console, so you don't have to worry about unrelated errors.

I tried your code as it is (just replacing the "biplane" with "toy_biplane_idle_model" as it comes from Apple) and there is no visible shadow at all

here is what I see https://imgur.com/a/ME3zftX

I downloaded the usdz model from HERE.  If you downloaded the model from another resource, then there may be a different hierarchy inside. I renamed the model to biplane.usdz for convenience.

yes, I downloaded it from here as well
but anyway, I was thinking about having a generic solution, something that works for every possible model entity

Run your app on the phone (not in the simulator) and you'll see the same imagery (including shadow) when you physically get close to the biplane.

As I understand you correctly, by a generic solution you mean a code that will help automatically find a ModelEntity in USDZ hierarchy in order to apply GroundingShadowComponent to it? Publish it as another question.

I run it on the phone too and see exactly the same thing.
I think there can't be a different hierarchy because the code would crash in that case (forced cast of findEntity).
Maybe its buggy.
But thank you for your time !

You're welcome! If .usdz models and my / your code are identical, then everything works 100%.

P. S. The original name of a model is toy_biplane_idle, not a toy_biplane_idle_model as you stated earlier in the comment .

yes, you are right, toy_biplane_idle. But this had no effect since the model was loaded correctly, just the shadow is not there.

Can you copy-paste my code and not use your code at all? What's the model of your iPhone, what's the version of iOS, Xcode, macOS, deployment target ?

I'm using macOS 15.1.1, iPadOS 18.1.1, Xcode 16.1, iPadPro 4th gen, deployment target 18.0.

here is your code 1:1 https://imgur.com/OQJLURh build with XCode 16.0 macOS Sonoma and I see exactly the same thing on iPhone XR iOS 18.1 https://imgur.com/3E1ORkU

Have you got closer to 3D model with your real phone? (I can send a screen video for you)

Nope, how can I do it ? But would it work in a .nonAR mode too ?

You don't read my comments carefully.   )))

Second time – Run your app on the phone (not in the simulator) and you'll see the same imagery (including shadow) when you physically get close to the biplane.

Have updated this post (included code for VR).

Now it works even in the XCode preview. PerspectiveCamera is what made it visible. Thanks a lot for your effort and bringing this to work as expected !
